# When is a continuous path stochastic process be representable as diffusion or Ito process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

When can a continuous path (Markovian) stochastic process in one dimension be represented as an Ito or a diffusion process? What are the examples when it can not be?

Comment: tbh, i am skeptical if you will get an answer, but good question.

Comment: Well, the classic examples of not being a diffusion are processes with jumps, which can be Markov.  There might be a way to use Chapman-Kolgomorov equations to specificy continuity, but I don't know it.

Comment: @Trurl: I specifically ask for "continuous path". Jumps are not continuous, so it does not count.

Comment: Crosspost: [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/151817/when-is-a-continuous-path-stochastic-process-be-representable-as-diffusion-or-it).

Comment: @saz: I posted here first. As you can see, nobody here had provided any answer, as Lost1 had predicted.

Comment: Yes, but for anyone looking for an answer (or even pondering answering this question) it is good to know that there is already an answer @MathOverflow.